# does anyone know how to know if an sbmjob finished?

Tags: db2-400

What I'm trying to do is execute 2 SBMJOBs, but first I need program A to finish, in order to execute program B. Does anyone know how to do it?

Program A:
SBMJOB CMD(CALL PGM(PROGRAM1) PARM(PARM1 PARM2)) JOB(PROGRAM1)

Program B:
To run this program, I need the A to finish first, but how can I validate that?
SBMJOB CMD(CALL PGM(PROGRAM2) PARM(PARM1 PARM2)) JOB(PROGRAM2)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to submit your two jobs on a JOBQ connected to a subsystem which let only one job process at a time.

Your second job will run naturally after the first is finished.

You can choose the JOBQ with the JOBQ parameter on the SBMJOB command.

QBATCH is by default a jobq with only one simultaneous job. But check before, it could have been changed on your system.

See the CHGJOBQE to change configuration on a jobq. General explanation on jobq and subsystem is here [IBM doc JOBS and job queues](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=jq-how-jobs-are-taken-from-multiple-job-queues)